# how to validate a checkbox with multiple forms?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, validation

i have 3 forms and a checkbox like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="confirm_agreement" value=yes <?php if (isset($_POST["confirm_agreement2"])) {print "checked";}?>>I agree

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/webscr" method="post">
      <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/x-click-but02.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
       <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
       <input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypal@exploretalent.com">
       <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
       <input type="hidden" name="no_note2" value="1">
       ...
       <input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
</form>

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/webscr" method="post">
      <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/x-click-but02.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
       <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
       <input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypal@exploretalent.com">
       <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
       <input type="hidden" name="no_note2" value="2">
       ...
       <input type="hidden" name="sra" value="2">
</form>

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/webscr" method="post">
      <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/x-click-but02.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
       <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
       <input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypal@exploretalent.com">
       <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
       <input type="hidden" name="no_note2" value="2">
       ...
       <input type="hidden" name="sra" value="2">
</form>
```

what i am trying to do is to validate the user clicking on that checkbox to submit any of those 3 forms.

if the user doesn't check the box then an alert comes up.

I know i need to use some java script, something like:

```
function checkCheckBoxes() {
if (document.frmTest.confirm_agreement.checked == false)
{
    alert ('You must agree with the User Agreement Terms!');
    return false;
}
}
```

then add `onsubmit="return checkCheckBoxes();"` on the forms, but this doesn't work.

Any ideas on how this should be done?

Thanks

Comment: It's a one-line snipped of jQuery, something like `$('form').submit(function () { if (!$('#confirm_agreement').is(':checked')) { alert('You must check the box'); return false } });` Is there any reason you're not using jQuery or some other JS library to make your life monumentally easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this as

```
function checkCheckBoxes() {
if (document.getElementsByName('confirm_agreement')[0].checked == false)
{
    alert ('You must agree with the User Agreement Terms!');
    return false;
}
}
```